# Derogatory way to refer to a smoker

Tags: phrase-request, insult

In English, one might say

> He smokes like a chimney.

Given the incredibly creative German insults that I've come across (see [this German.SE question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28665/derogatory-word-for-someone-who-wears-glasses)), I'd like to know what (derogatory) terms/expressions are used for smokers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a smoker smells of cold smoke (and for a non-smoker all smokers do),  he is **ein laufender Aschenbecher** (a walking ashtray)

Comment: I often hear "walking ashtray" in English also.

Answer (score 10):

"Er raucht wie ein Kamin" - I haven't encountered that one yet.

> [Er raucht wie ein Schlot](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/rauchen_wie_ein_Schlot)

with "Schlot" being a high, tall thin chimney of a factory or coal power plant, but not the regular chimney through which Santa Claus enters.

Another for someone who smokes lots would be

> Kettenraucher (=chain smoker)

Comment: +1 both terms are common (albeit not really derogative)

Answer (score 4):

I never heard anybody saying these expressions, but a male smoker I personally call

**Luftbekacker** (air shitter, someone who shits in the air).

And a female smoker I call

**Tabakschlampe** (tobacco slut).

The female version of **Luftbekacker** is **Luftbekackerin**.

Accordingly instead of **rauchen** (to smoke) I say **die Luft bekacken** (to shit in the air).

Comment: I've heard Tabakschlampe (for males and females), but very seldom and most times as selfdescription of smokers, e.g. "Ich muss mal wieder raus eine Rauchen, du weißt ja, was für eine Tabakschlampe ich bin. Ich kann Tabak einfach nicht wiederstehen."

Comment: @Iris Probably because it would be *very* derogative to call others like that :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz, I don't think so. I think it is less bad than e.g. Laufender Aschenbecher. Btw, I've never hear Luftbekacker.

Comment: @Iris I'd find it difficult to rank them. But I'd rather expect to hear them either as an insult or maybe mockingly among really close friends. In contrast, the words from Susanne's post I could also imagine among more distant people, e.g. colleagues. And I agree, learned quite a few new words as well.

Answer (score 3):

As another alternative: The [*Cigarette Smoking Man* character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smoking_Man) from the [*X Files*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files) was sometimes derogatively referred to as *Cancer Man*<sup>1</sup>. In the German dubbing, this was (in my opinion, fittingly) translated as **Krebskandidat**.

<sup>1</sup>: He was so high up in the ranks of a secret agency that even his name was secret and unknown to the protagonists for much of the series. As he usually was rather on the antagonistic side, quite some characters had reasons to hold a grudge against him and refer to him in not-too-polite a manner.

Answer (score 2):

*Teerhalde*, *Suchti*, *Quarzer*, *Dampfer*, *Stummellutscher*, *Paffer* (obviously) are terms I have come across.

*Kiffer* targeting at ("normal") cigarette smokers I have heard as well (Even if *kiffen* it is an expression for smoking pot, normally).

Comment: +1 für Quarzer, Suchti und Stummellutscher. -1 for Kiffer.

Comment: Nicht fair: 0+3-1 = 2 :D

Comment: Da hast du Recht ;)